# why css3 :nth-child (4n) count not correct

Tags: html, css

[image]my target is every one row have four column and I used `:nth-child` but not work as i expected only work in first row and the second row the border div is in the 3rd column.

**Html**

```
    <div class="workplace">some text here</div>
    <div class="workplace">some text here</div>
    <div class="workplace">some text here</div>
    <div class="workplace">some text here</div>

    <div class="workplace">some text here</div>
    <div class="workplace">some text here</div>
    <div class="workplace">some text here</div>
    <div class="workplace">some text here</div>

    <div class="workplace">some text here</div>
```

**css**

```
 .workplace:nth-child(4n){
    border:1px solid red;
    }
```

my question is: why this happen is this because of conflict of other style?

Comment: in the `second row` the border is in `3rd div` I expect it to border in `4th div` in total count of `div` is in `8th div`

Comment: Seems to work for me. http://jsfiddle.net/3Ey8F/

Comment: I created the same fiddle as Simcha and can't see anything but the expected behavior. On a related note, nth-child works on elements, not classes.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to create a `table` using `divs`. There are *no columns* in your HTML, hence why your CSS is not behaving as expected. You are trying to target tabular-style elements where there are none.

Comment: It's ok to use tables to display data in more than one dimension. As long as you're using it to display data and not for layout, you're fine.

Comment: Share your Full HTML and CSS Here or reproduce it in jsfiddle.